# WPF Element Rotation inside a layout

Tags: wpf

I want to rotate a element inside a canvas using RotateTransfer object.It is rotating fine but
sometime it is moving outside of the canvas.Can anyone suggest how to restrict rotation to outside of canvas.

Answer (score 2):

You mean to say that when the element rotates it goes outside the boundaries of the Canvas?

Can you try to use `LayoutTranform` instead of `RenderTransform`.

Comment: Yes this what i actually did & the requirement is achieved.Thanks a lot for your post.